# How to use LogonUser properly to impersonate domain user from workgroup client

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-2.0, impersonation

[ASP.NET: Impersonate against a domain on VMWare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/278132/asp-net-impersonate-against-a-domain-on-vmware)

This question is what I am asking, but the answer does not provide details on how the _token is derived. It seems to only use `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token` so there's no impersonation happening.

[Can I impersonate a user on a different Active Directory domain in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997001/can-i-impersonate-a-user-on-a-different-active-directory-domain-in-net)

This next question has conflicting answers, with the accepted one bearing a comment "I'm beginning to suspect that my problem lies elsewhere."  Not helpful.

[LogonUser works only for my domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993418/logonuser-works-only-for-my-domain)

This next question seems to imply it is not possible, but it deals with 2 domains so I am not sure if it is relevant.

My real question is:

- **Is it possible?** And if so,
- **How?** or **Where did I go wrong?**

What I have tried so far is, using the code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

```
bool returnValue = LogonUser(user, domain, password,
            LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
            ref tokenHandle);
// after this point, returnValue = false
```

The Win32 error is

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

Answer (score 64):

Very few posts suggest using `LOGON_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS` instead of `LOGON_TYPE_NETWORK` or `LOGON_TYPE_INTERACTIVE`. I had an impersonation issue with one machine connected to a domain and one not, and this fixed it.
The last code snippet in [this post](http://www.cstruter.com/blog/270) suggests that impersonating across a forest does work, but it doesn't specifically say anything about trust being set up. So this may be worth trying:

```
const int LOGON_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3;
bool returnValue = LogonUser(user, domain, password,
            LOGON_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50,
            ref tokenHandle);
```

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184.aspx) that `LOGON_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS` only works when using `LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50`.

Comment: Be aware that `LOGON_TYPE_NEW_CREDENTIALS` appears not to validate the credentials until they're used to access a network resource, so it can't be used for authentication the way `LOGON_TYPE_NETWORK` can.

Comment: I had the same issue impersonating against a different domain than the one my application ran in.  The other domain also did not have trust.  I would receive the nonsensical error "The system cannot find the file specified".  Changing 0,2 to 9,3 like you suggested above worked!  Now I can read in files from a file share on a different domain.  Thanks man, you saved me from a lot of pain!

Comment: Thanks, it works, but nevertheless the whole issue is strange. I tried to authenticate to impersonate within the same network and I always got the 'Unknown user name or bad password' message when using LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE. On my dev machine all worked fine. I'd love to trace the cause to the bottom, but where shall I start?

Comment: @Daniel Good question. I only found this by experimenting with the options given in the docs, not because I knew how or why it works ;-)

Answer (score 29):

this works for me, full working example (I wish more people would do this):

```
//logon impersonation
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; // DllImport
using System.Security.Principal; // WindowsImpersonationContext
using System.Security.Permissions; // PermissionSetAttribute

...

class Program {

    // obtains user token
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(string pszUsername, string pszDomain, string pszPassword,
        int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    // closes open handes returned by LogonUser
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    public void DoWorkUnderImpersonation() {
        //elevate privileges before doing file copy to handle domain security
        WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
        IntPtr userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonationDomain"];
        string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonationUser"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImpersonationPassword"];

        try {
            Console.WriteLine("windows identify before impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            // if domain name was blank, assume local machine
            if (domain == "")
                domain = System.Environment.MachineName;

            // Call LogonUser to get a token for the user
            bool loggedOn = LogonUser(user,
                                        domain,
                                        password,
                                        LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                                        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                                        ref userHandle);

            if (!loggedOn) {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception impersonating user, error code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return;
            }

            // Begin impersonating the user
            impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle);

            Console.WriteLine("Main() windows identify after impersonation: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

            //run the program with elevated privileges (like file copying from a domain server)
            DoWork();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception impersonating user: " + ex.Message);
        } finally {
            // Clean up
            if (impersonationContext != null) {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
            }

            if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
                CloseHandle(userHandle);
            }
        }
    }


    private void DoWork() {
        //everything in here has elevated privileges

        //example access files on a network share through e$ 
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\domainserver\e$\images", "*.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you prevent the contents of `password` from leaking via memory dumps or attached debuggers on a compromised system? I notice that you left it hanging around in memory.

Comment: these APIs are so picky. I got almost the same solution, and it failed because of the wrong combination of logonprovider and logontype. interactive in connection with default is fine, while newcredentials only works with winnt50... using this approach, `Environment.Username` really returns the impersonated account, if that is what you need use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Don't know if you've solved this or not, but what I was really trying to do was access a network share with AD credentials. `WNetAddConnection2()` is what you need to use in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I have been successfull at impersonating users in another domain, but **only** with a trust set up between the 2 domains.

```
var token = IntPtr.Zero;
var result = LogonUser(userID, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token);
if (result)
{
    return WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a SecureString:

```
var password = new SecureString();
var phPassword phPassword = Marshal.SecureStringToGlobalAllocUnicode(password);
IntPtr phUserToken;
LogonUser(username, domain, phPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,  LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out phUserToken);
```

And:

```
Marshal.ZeroFreeGlobalAllocUnicode(phPassword);
password.Dispose();
```

Function definition:

```
private static extern bool LogonUser(
  string pszUserName,
  string pszDomain,
  IntPtr pszPassword,
  int dwLogonType,
  int dwLogonProvider,
  out IntPtr phToken);
```

Comment: Yes the doc of the underlying winapi is quite clear on that. Quote "When you have finished using the password, clear the password from memory by calling the SecureZeroMemory function. For more information about protecting passwords, see Handling Passwords."

Answer (score 0):

Invalid login/password could be also related to issues in your DNS server - that's what happened to me and cost me good 5 hours of my life. See if you can specify ip address instead on domain name.

Comment: So what was the DNS issue. I think I have this issue on one of our sites

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was when my workstation was on one domain, but I needed to authenticate to a server on a *different* domain:

- ERROR: `"Exception impersonating user, error code: 1326"`
- SOLUTION: Added `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` as a fallback to Impersonate/LogonUser()

**Impersonation.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace TestDBAccess
{
    public class Impersonation : IDisposable
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String Username, String Domain, String Password, int LogonType, int LogonProvider, out IntPtr Token);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK = 3;
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH = 4;
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE = 5;
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_UNLOCK = 7;
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 8;
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;

        private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
        private IntPtr userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        public Impersonation(string user, string domain, string password)
        {
            // Extract domain/username from user string
            string[] principal = user.Split('\\');
            if (principal.Length == 2)
            {
                domain = principal[0];
                user = principal[1];
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domain))
                domain = GetDefaultDomain();

            // Call LogonUser to get a token for the user
            bool loggedOn =
                LogonUser(user, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out userHandle);
            if (!loggedOn)
            {
                int ierr = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (ierr == 1326)
                {
                    loggedOn =
                        LogonUser(user, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS,
                            LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out userHandle);
                }
                if (!loggedOn)
                    throw new Exception("Exception impersonating user, error code: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            // Begin impersonating the user
            impersonationContext = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle);
        }

        public static string GetDefaultDomain ()
        {
            return System.Environment.UserDomainName;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Clean up
            if (impersonationContext != null)
                impersonationContext.Undo();

            if (userHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(userHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

**ExampleClient.cs**

```
Impersonation Impersonation = null;
try
{
    Impersonation = new Impersonation(username, null, password);
    LogMsg("Attempting to connect to (" + dbInstance.instance + ")...");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string sql = edtTestSql.Text;
        LogMsg("Attempting to query (" + sql + ")...");
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    LogMsg("next row: " + DumpRow(reader));
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogMsg(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (Impersonation != null)
        Impersonation.Dispose();
}
```