# var di = new DirectoryInfo(path) throws exception until I use Windows Explorer to open the path for a first time

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(Root);
var diList = di.GetDirectories();
```

The above crashes when accessing the text path 'Root' that is located on the network. I only occurs when a user first logs into Windows 7 (not tested on other OS's).  If a user uses windows Explorer to navigate to the specified path, then di is able to retrieve the directories.

I know doing a catch and prompting the user to click a link that opens windows explorer and navigates to the path can be done but I'm not one for work arounds.  I want my program to be able to establish the connection to the network path without requiring Windows explorer to do it first.

The exception:

```
System.IO.IOException: The network name cannot be found.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path,string originalUserPath,
  String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler,
  Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetDirectories(String searchPattern,
 SearchOption searchOption) at Controls.ValidationControl.LoadDBox(Object sender,
 RoutedEventArgs e)
in c:\Controls\ValidationControl.xaml.cs:line 1010
```

Thank you in advance for your support,
John

Comment: Can you share the actual exception that is happening when it "crashes"?

Comment: {System.IO.IOException: The network name cannot be found.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path,string originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetDirectories(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption) at Controls.ValidationControl.LoadDBox(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in c:\Controls\ValidationControl.xaml.cs:line 1010

Comment: Note: private const string Root = @"\\networkPath";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft's security will prevent you from accessing SharePoint via UNC using credentials captured by an application.  Therefore, after trying all above solutions and 3 other Network access classes, none would see the path and let me login so I simply used

```
Process.Start(dir);
```

and prompt the user as to what is going on. Windows explorer launches, using the user's credentials and navigates to the path where Windows then uses the user's domain account to login to SharePoint. Windows can do it. Programmers that don't work for Microsoft can't.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said it's happening on network folders, my first inclination is that the windows process that this app is running under doesn't have security access to read the directory info.  When the user browses to this folder, the security is authenticated, and so your app can now read it.

Does the app work if Root is a local folder?

Comment: You are correct. Windows Authentication is required to access the resource, which is not granted until after the user uses Explorer to navigate to the network path. How do I call for Windows to access the permissions manually from my code using C#?

Answer (score 1):

Most probable reason seems that user need to log in to access the network path. This does not seems to happen until the path is accessed via `Explorer`. Try mapping the network folder as drive on your local machine and set it to login automatically. This might help it.

EDIT:- As pointed by [Scottie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583090/13198) in another answer the credentials under which the program runs may also need access to the shared folder.

**EDIT#2:-** You can use `P/Invoke` to pass Credentials [[Ref]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/295703/13198). Or you can call `LogonUser` method to do impersonation as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx). Further details regarding impersonation and `LogonUser` can be found in [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5023607/13198).

Comment: So, in C#, how do I call to access the network path using the existing user's login? 

var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
.....

Comment: I tried both of the above and neither would grant me access. Thank you for the help though.