# Impersonating to X509Store.Add to StoreName.Root - The Request Is Not Supported

Tags: c#, impersonation, x509certificate2, cryptographicexception

I cannot find anything related to the error that I am encountering.

The problem is that I am encountering a CryptographicException on `store.Add` below:

> "The request is not supported."

The [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148583(v=vs.110).aspx) is not very helpful, it states that:

> The certificate could not be added to the store.

I used the [following code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189898/installing-pfx-certificate-on-a-different-user) as a guide, with the following change:

- They are adding to StoreName.My and **I want to add to
  StoreName.Root**
- I want to use an IDisposable class to impersonate the user.

My proof of concept code (abridged/shoddy):

```cs
public class UserLogonImpersonator : IDisposable
{
    private WindowsImpersonationContext _impersonationContext = null;
    private const int LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    private const int PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
        private static extern int LogonUser(
        string lpszUserName,
        string lpszDomain,
        string lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);

    public UserLogonImpersonator()
    {
        _impersonationContext = null;
        IntPtr userHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        const string domain = "domain";
        const string user = "user";
        const string hcpw = "password";

        try
        {
            int logonResult = LogonUser(user, domain, hcpw, 
                LOGON_INTERACTIVE, PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref userHandle);
            bool isLoggedOn = logonResult != 0;

            if (isLoggedOn)
            {
                _impersonationContext = 
                    WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(userHandle);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Handle Exception
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // UndoImpersonation();
    }

    // Private methods ...
}

public class CertService
{
    public void AddCertToRootStore()
    {
        using(new UserLogonImpersonator())
        {
            X509Certificate2 rootCert = 
                new X509Certificate2(certData.CertFilePath);
            X509Store store = 
                new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
            store.Add(rootCert);
            store.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I can remove the impersonation and no exceptions are thrown, but that is not the correct user's store.

With the impersonation, I can put the cert into `StoreName.AuthRoot` without exception.  This is not the store that I want the cert to go into.

Neither of these exception-free solutions will work.  I require that the program be run with elevated privileges and go into another user's store.

Comment: I added my solution below.  Maybe someone can shed some light on why this happens in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing it manually.

I wanted to do this to automate "test chain certificates."  Our third party CA gave us a set of certificates for a .local domain.

Our real-life use case would already have the root and chain certificate installed.