# Login with Windows credentials in .NET Windows application

Tags: .net, windows, authentication

I'd like to use Windows credentials as login credentials for my .NET desktop application.

That is, I'd like to authenticate the application user aganist Windows users. Application user might be different to the currently logged in user in Windows.

Once the user is authenticated, I'd like to retrieve the list of the groups it belongs to.

I'have been searching for a while, but I can't find any clear clue.

Comment: What kind of .net application you mean? Is it a web application, or a desktop application?

Comment: @Nikolay Desktop application

Comment: I think you might want to search around the "impersonation" and related topics. Like this one as an example: (WindowsIdentity.Impersonate, LogonUser): https://stackoverflow.com/a/17217167/929187